# How do I change the name of a label if a specific radio button is checked?

Tags: c#

Through coding, if lets say radioButton2 is checked, how do I have the Text property for the Label label1 change to, for example, "Enter a different value"?

```
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, why can't you just set the `Text` property of label in your event handler like

```
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       label1.Text = "Enter a different value";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple you should keep exploring but just for help

```
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if(radioButton2.Checked)
           {

              label1.Text = "Enter a different value";
           }
        }
```